# How to reload a systemd service when using Chef

Tags: chef-infra, systemd

I have a systemd service that is managed using Chef.

What is the Chef way to do a `systemctl daemon-reload`?

So for example as shown below, I can perform a reload of my myservice but this doensn't do a systemctl daemon-reload.

```
template '/etc/systemd/system/myservice.service do
  notifies :reload,'service[myservice]', :immediately 
end

service 'myservice' do
  supports status: true ...
  action %i[start enable]
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can manage Systemd service definitions using the [systemd_unit resource](https://docs.chef.io/resources/systemd_unit/). This way, if the service configuration changes it will trigger a reload with the `triggers_reload` (set to `true` by default) property.

Since you are using a template, you could use the `systemd_unit` resource with `reload` action for your service.

```rb
template '/etc/systemd/system/myservice.service' do
  notifies :reload, 'systemd_unit[myservice.service]', :immediately 
end

systemd_unit 'myservice.service' do
  action :nothing
end
```

Other option is to create an `execute` resource, and run the actual `daemon-reload` command:

```rb
template '/etc/systemd/system/myservice.service' do
  notifies :run, 'execute[daemon-reload]', :immediately 
end

execute 'daemon-reload' do
  command 'systemctl daemon-reload'
  action :nothing
end
```

Comment: Calling the `:reload` action on `systemd_unit[myservice.service]` via a notify, like in your first example [will not cause a `daemon-reload`](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/1f4ec9fd3587ae4efdc3b20b273bd64164328063/lib/chef/provider/systemd_unit.rb#L192-L201). It instead tells the service in question to reload. Of your two examples, only the second method, executing `systemctl daemon-reload` works. The Chef `systemd_unit` only triggers a `daemon-reload` when a systemd unit is created or deleted and the `triggers_reload` attribute is `True`.

Comment: Good point. In that case, the service would have to be managed (created/deleted) using `systemd_unit` resource itself rather than `template`, with service configuration specified as `content`.